# How to add more colors to plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rworldmap

I have dataset like this

```
Country        GDP
Afghanistan    20315
Albania        12800
```

My code is as follows

```
library(rworldmap)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)

countries = read.csv("countries.csv", na.strings = " NA")
countries$GDP = as.numeric(as.character(countries$GDP))

sPDF = joinCountryData2Map(countries, joinCode = "NAME", nameJoinColumn =    "Country", verbose = TRUE)
mapParams = mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot = "GDP", missingCountryCol = "dark grey", addLegend = FALSE, oceanCol = "lightsteelblue2")
do.call(addMapLegend, c(mapParams, legendWidth = 0.5, legendMar = 2))
```

And this is the plot I'm getting

[image]
As you can see, a lot countries are colored red because only 7 colors are used in the legend. How can I specify more colors to be used? I'd like to get a plot like this: [image]

Comment: you can probably adjust the `colourPalette` parameter of `mapCountryData` function to whatever colours you want

Comment: Awesome. I added this
`colourPalette = brewer.pal(9, "RdPu")`
and it made it slightly better. I wish I could add more colors, but apparently a maximum of 9 colors can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `numCats` argument to set the number of categories. The `RColorBrewer` palette has 9 colours but `rworldmap` will interpolate between them to give you the number asked for.

Also you can experiment with the `catMethod` argument which determines how the categorisation is done and can radically alter what the map looks like as explained [here](http://rpubs.com/danielkirsch/styling-choropleth-maps).

`mapCountryData(sPDF, numCats=20, catMethod="fixedWidth", colourPalette=brewer.pal(9, "RdPu"))`